# What type of noun is ‘classwork’

Tags: nouns

In the sentence ‘The teacher collected the classwork’, is the noun ‘classwork’ a collective or concrete noun? Classwork is something tangible so it could be concrete but then we use ‘it’ when referring to it so it makes me think it is collective. Thanks

Comment: Why should it not be both?

Comment: "The farmer collected the wheat."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @KateBunting so succinctly stated in her commentary, it can be both.

"Classwork" as a collective noun describes the abstract or abstracted concept of work being done in class. It has a meaning similar to "curriculum".

> Classwork here will consist of mostly linear algebra but also some simple analysis.

"Classwork" as a concrete noun describes concrete, tangible examples of the above concept. Like in your example:

> The teacher collected the classwork.